# Make a page load at the bottom and move assets up on scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is for a class project. I  am making a one page site about space for kids.  The idea is to have the page load at the bottom and as you scroll a rocket blasts off etc.  I can't find a solution to getting it to load at the bottom without specifying the anchor in the URL.

Comment: You're taking your question as a Java question, but are you sure? Is it a Java question (doubt)? Or is it for Javascript (more likely)? If you use the wrong tags, you attract the wrong experts, so you'll want to be sure about this.

Comment: You are right, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use JavaScript to scroll to the bottom of the page when the window loads.

```
window.addEventListener('load',function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
}, false);
```

In an HTML document:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Page title</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.addEventListener('load',function() {
        window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
    }, false);
</script>
<!-- The rest of your document -->
```

Comment: So I'm really new to JavaScript... Would that just go in a <script> tag at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, though it could also go at the top. I've edited the answer to show a full HTML page markup.

Comment: One more thing? Will that actually cause all the content to scroll past the screen, or if I put it at the top, for instance, will it go to the bottom before the rest of the page loads?

Comment: No matter where you put it, this will cause the page to immediately jump to the bottom (not scroll past) once the page is FULLY loaded—including all images, etc. If you want it to jump before the images load, you can change the `'load'` to `'DOMContentLoaded'`, but if the height of the page later changes, say because images that have a height load in, then you may not end up at the very bottom of the page, just near it. See http://jsfiddle.net/6j71fxeg/ for an example where a large image pushes the page beyond where you scroll to when using `'DOMContentLoaded'`.

Comment: I think this will have one long background image, with other smaller images with a higher z index. So if I give the body a height equal to the background, will it work?

Comment: I don't see why not. :)